# CSS cascading precedence of origin and importance

Tags: css, css-specificity, css-cascade

According to the [specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#cascading), the precedence of declaration origins is as follows (Top wins):

> 1. Transition declarations [css-transitions-1]
> 2. Important user agent declarations
> 3. Important user declarations
> 4. Important author declarations
> 5. Animation declarations [css-animations-1]
> 6. **Normal author declarations**
> 7. **Normal user declarations**
> 8. Normal user agent declarations

I'm trying to verify that the normal author declaration (6) wins over the normal user declaration (7), but I think I get the opposite result:

[image]

In the above example, I have an external css file (*style.css*) that declares the color of the `p` element as `green`.

Then I add some user style, declaring the color of the same selector as `blue`.

I expect that the author declaration (green) will win over the user declaration (blue), but the opposite happens.

Any ideas of what is going on? Maybe I'm doing something wrong in the example?

Comment: What is the precedence of these two files like which one is first and second

Comment: if I am not wrong, the author declaration is the blue one and ther other is the user, no?

Comment: Are we sure hacking additional rules in via inspector counts as “user declaration”? The document you’re quoting from says, _“User Origin - The user may be able to specify style information for a particular document. For example, the user may specify a file that contains a style sheet or the user agent may provide an interface that generates a user style sheet (or behaves as if it did).”_ - I’m not so sure dev tools qualify here, resp. I think interpretations of that could go different ways …?

Comment: @Awais, I first loaded the page only with the style.css (green) and then I've added a new rule (blue) from the dev tools

Comment: So the precedence is high for `blue` color form `dev` as it comes after `style.css`

Comment: So, how can I verify that the author's style wins over user's styles if I can only add user styles after author styles?

Comment: @Temani Afif: No, the color: green is author-level. Not sure about the color: blue one, but I would not be surprised if the inspector-stylesheet is also author-level.

Comment: @04FS: I agree. Dev tools are focused on debugging author styles in the first place, so I wouldn't be surprised if the inspector-stylesheet was made author-level so it would operate on the same cascade level as other author styles, thereby having an effect on them.

Answer (score 2):

A custom CSS applied from the dev tools is not treated as *user* style sheet, but as an *inline, author* one. That's why it beats the external CSS declaration.

afaik support for user style sheets was [removed from Chrome back in 2014](https://codereview.chromium.org/66383005/), and the only way to set them is through extensions. [For Firefox, you can edit userContent.css](https://davidwalsh.name/firefox-user-stylesheet)

Answer (score 0):

Add "**!important**" in stylesheet on color. See Below

```
p{
    color: green !important;
}
```